Unhandled Runtime Error. TypeError: Cannot read properties of null(reading 'useRef')- NextJS App with React Scroll Parallax
I have built a simple website with NextJS (Typescript) Front-end and Express back-end (also Tailwind config). Everything was working fine until I tried to incorporate react-scroll-parallax and since I have received the following message:
("unhandled runtime error: Typeerror: cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef'))
Steps I have taken to fix include:

I have tried to dynamically imported Parralaxprovider to try to make it run only on the client-side
I have tried to wrap the parralax-related code in 'useEffect'
I have checked that ParallaxProvider is wrapped around entire application in _app.tsx
I have removed 'node_modules' and 'package.json', cleared npm cache and reinstalled dependencies
I am searched for this issue on other posts on StackOverflow. There are others who have had the same issue, which I have tried to draw from, but I am struggling to apply to my context (probably because I am still quite new to using NextJS).

I have a few components rendered on a page "Index.tsx" but to start I am currently trying to apply a parallax scrolling effect to one component "container". I have attached my code below. I am new to NextJS as well as using parallax effect so any advise would be welcome.
_app.tsx
import React, { ReactNode, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useParallax } from 'react-scroll-parallax';

interface ContainerProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  bgColor?: string;
  maxWidth?: string;
  backgroundImage?: string;
  backgroundOpacity?: number;
}

const Container: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({
  children,
  bgColor = 'bg-white',
  maxWidth = 'max-w-3xl',
  backgroundImage,
  backgroundOpacity = 0.8,
}) => {
  const parallaxRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Ensure the parallax effect is applied only on the client-side
    const { ref } = useParallax({ speed: -30 });
    parallaxRef.current = ref.current;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={parallaxRef} className={`relative ${bgColor} ${maxWidth} mx-auto p-4`}>
      {backgroundImage && (
        <div
          className="absolute inset-0 bg-cover bg-center z-0 fixed-background"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
            opacity: backgroundOpacity,
          }}
        />
      )}
      <div className="relative z-10">
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Container;


Container.tsx
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { useParallax } from 'react-scroll-parallax';

interface ContainerProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  bgColor?: string;
  maxWidth?: string;
  backgroundImage?: string;
  backgroundOpacity?: number;
}

const Container: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({
  children,
  bgColor = 'bg-white',
  maxWidth = 'max-w-3xl',
  backgroundImage,
  backgroundOpacity = 0.8,
}) => {
  const parallax = useParallax({ speed: -30 });

  return (
    <div ref={parallax.ref} className={`relative ${bgColor} ${maxWidth} mx-auto p-4`}>
      {backgroundImage && (
        <div
          className="absolute inset-0 bg-cover bg-center z-0 fixed-background"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
            opacity: backgroundOpacity,
          }}
        />
      )}
      <div className="relative z-10">
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Container;

index.tsx
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import ScrollDownMessage from '../components/ScrollDownMessage';
import MainContent from '../components/MainContent';
import Container from '../components/Container';
import { fetchData } from '../services/api';

interface DataItem {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const HomePage: React.FC = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<DataItem[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await fetchData();
        setData(data);
      } catch (error: any) {
        setError(error.message);
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    getData();
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error}</p>;

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 overflow-hidden">
      <Container maxWidth="max-w-7xl" backgroundImage="/images/Background-image.jpg" backgroundOpacity={0.5}>
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen">
          <Header />
          <ScrollDownMessage />
        </div>
        <MainContent />
        <div>
          <h2>Fetched Data:</h2>
          {Array.isArray(data) && data.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <p>{item.name}</p>
              {/* Display other fields as needed */}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;


